# docker-compose volumes version 3 syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

version 3 of docker compose allows volumes to be specified. Although I'm looking to use it in a way I'm not sure if it works, can someone provide some insight, here is what I am looking for:

We have a lot of apps, so I'd like to specify the volumes area in one spot

```
volumes:
   app: ./app
   microservice: ./microservice
   anothermicroservice: ./anothermicroservice
   ...

services:
   app:
      ...
      volumes:
         - app/.git:/usr/src/.git
         - app/src:/usr/src/src
   microservice:
      ...
      volumes:
          - microservice/.git:/usr/src/.git
          - microservice/src:/usr/src/src
   ...
```

This possible? Or anything similar? thanks

Comment: so there is no way to specify it at the `volumes: codevolume:` area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know the volume syntax does not offer it.

But i would suggest using [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/), e.g. with a .env file

```
$ cat .env
APP=./app
MICROSERVICE=./microservice

$ cat docker-compose.yml
services:
  app:
    volumes:
     - $APP/.git:/usr/src/.git
     - $APP/src:/usr/src/src
  microservice:
    volumes:
      - $MICROSERVICE/.git:/usr/src/.git
      - $MICROSERVICE/src:/usr/src/src
```